# How to get a list of system sounds in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm working on an alarm app for Windows Phone 8 and I'd like to let the user pick from the available alarms tones (like the built-in "Alarms" app has). Is that set of sounds available to third-party apps? If so, how can I access it?

Answer (score 2):

The list of built-in Alarm sounds isn't currently exposed for 3rd party apps. If this is something you'd like to see in future releases please open a new feature suggestion on [wpdev uservoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com) with your usecase.